How to add a row with formula to a protected worksheet using a Variable?
I have wrote a script to add a row with formula to a protected worksheet. The selectedSheet is mapped to the active sheet, which is password protected.
In the protected worksheet, there is a table for user to provide the information by keying in the information (Column B and C). The formulas (Column D to E) will then calculate the results after user has keyed in the fields (Column B to C).
In the protected worksheet, there is a button linked to the script to execute the new row insertion. The new row will be inserted when the button is pressed. The inserted new row will have the Column B and C for user to key in the information and the formulas are auto populated to the Column D to E.  When the button is pressed, the sequence are:

a. It will un-protect the active sheet;
b. It will insert a new row at row 19;
c. After the row insertion, the formatting of to the active worksheet is applied; and
d. The active sheet is protected back using the same password.

Once the button is pressed. this allows the users to key in new information to the row inserted. The script is working fine.
But however, when I changed it from getRange("19:19") to a variable- LRW=19 and put use it as getRange("LRW:LRW"), it does not work.
Does anyone know what is the issue and kindly assist to help me to resolve this issue. Many thanks in advance for helping. I am new to the Excel Office Script!
Tried Debugging and asking around for help but to no avail

You're trying to put the name of a variable directly into a string. You need to build a string using the variable: getRange("" & LRW & ":" & LRW)

Please post the code you have tried so far.
